# How can I add a align buttons to the toolbar in Quill?

Tags: quill

I'm trying to add alignment buttons to the Quill editor toolbar.

The toolbar [documentation](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/) isn't very detailed. It shows how to have a select for the alignment options but I'd like a set of toggle buttons side-by-side. Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do `align: 'center'`, similar to the `header: 3` example in the [docs](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/#container). Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKdEgN

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ align: '' }, { align: 'center' }, { align: 'right' }, { align: 'justify' }]
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});
```

Comment: This kind of stuff should really be in the documentation seeing how many people are using it (it's got almost 17k stars on Github). I was close to starting to read the source code to see what options are available.

Comment: This kind of stuff is in the docs as linked in my answer? If the expectation is every permutation of possible configurations is in the docs then the docs would get very long given the configurability of Quill.

Comment: That's why it's called documentation in my view. Not to take anything away from the awesomeness of the library but it's lacking in certain places. Also, I've not found anything about creating custom themes and having custom class names to style.