# Quill toolbar alignment buttons

Tags: quill

I'm trying to add alignment buttons to the toolbar. I'm using the method of laying out the toolbar using html elements. What I'd like to know is if it's possible to have alignment buttons represented as discrete buttons on the toolbar instead of being in a dropdown.

All of the examples that I've seen so far use the dropdown approach. Is what I'm after even possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add a dropdown option as it's own button by adding a value attribute to it like so:

```
<button class="ql-align" value="center">
```

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    toolbar: '#toolbar'
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.js"></script>

<div id="toolbar">
  <span class="ql-formats">
    <button class="ql-align" value=""></button>
    <button class="ql-align" value="center"></button>
    <button class="ql-align" value="right"></button>
    <button class="ql-align" value="justify"></button>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

I'd suggest using the shorthand in the js for the toolbar, so not using a custom html toolbar. Then by writing

```
toolbar: [{ align: '' }, { align: 'center' }, { align: 'right' }, { align: 'justify' }]
```

you can define 4 discrete alignment buttons as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45687960/how-can-i-add-a-align-buttons-to-the-toolbar-in-quill) by @[jhchen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235771/jhchen). He also has a nice example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKdEgN). Otherwise I'd assume you could achieve the same though html (based solely on looking at the source code the shorthand generates):

```
<span class="ql-formats">
  <button type="button" class="ql-align" value="">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> 
      <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="15" y1="9" y2="9"></line>
      <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="13" y1="14" y2="14"></line>
      <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="9" y1="4" y2="4"></line>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="ql-align" value="center">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 18 18">
      <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="9" y2="9"></line>
      <line class="ql-stroke" x1="14" x2="4" y1="14" y2="14"></line>
      <line class="ql-stroke" x1="12" x2="6" y1="4" y2="4"></line>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="ql-align" value="right">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> 
      <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="9" y2="9"></line>
      <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="5" y1="14" y2="14"></line>
      <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="9" y1="4" y2="4"></line>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="ql-align" value="justify">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 18 18">
      <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="9" y2="9"></line>
      <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="14" y2="14"></line>
      <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="3" y1="4" y2="4"></line>
    </svg>
  </button>
</span>
```

However, I would honestly suggest you use the shorthand, it keeps it all nice and clean and it ensures it works. Furthermore, it still allows you to add custom buttons ([check this](https://codepen.io/nik10110/pen/PbyNoW))

Answer (score 3):

You can use `select` tag with `option` for dropdown. Use `select` with class `ql-align` and its inside add each `option` with value attributes as "", "center", "right" and "justify" respectively.

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    toolbar: '#toolbar'
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>

<div id="toolbar">
  <select class="ql-align">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="center"></option>
    <option value="right"></option>
    <option value="justify"></option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following line to your Quill toolbar html and Quill will take care of the rest.

```
<select class="ql-align"></select>
```